# TYPO3 how duplicate content in severals page

Tags: content-management-system, admin, typo3

- I have a TYPO3 website.
- I have 4 contents in my home page which I had created with TemplaVoila (flexible content).

I want to know if there is an easy way to duplicate these contents in all the others pages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TemplaVoila allows you to reference ContentElements with special icon, which means that you insert it on some page and then you creates a references. If "first" CE changes, all references reflect it automatically.

Optionally, if all CE's are places in one TV's column you can use [TV Content Slide](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kb_tv_cont_slide) extension by Bernhard Kraft.

Comment: Hi,
how can i use TV content slide, i dont find so much help on the internet. Regards,

Comment: Did you try included manual??? it's the same as in the repo: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/kb_tv_cont_slide/current/

Answer (score 0):

Just map that content using typoscript using the below code and use it:

```
lib.leftcolumncontents = COA
lib.leftcolumncontents{
    5 = RECORDS
    5 {
        tables = tt_content
        source = 26  # content element id
    }
    15 = RECORDS
    15 {
        tables = tt_content
        source = 36  # content element id
    }
}
```